# How to use a month index in a count function in R using Pipr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following problem: I have a dataframe with 3 columns, line number, date, and a single word. I am trying to perform text analysis on GitHub commit comments using the https://www.tidytextmining.com/ method. I would like to have my aggregate sentiment score on a quarterly basis rather than by the number of comments which i did by `count(index = line %/% 10, sentiment) %>%`. Is there an easy way to count all my "sentiment scores" by quarter?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

```
single_word_with_date$date <- substr(single_word_with_date$date,1,nchar(single_word_with_date$date)-10)

single_word_with_date$date <- as.Date(single_word_with_date$date , format = "%Y-%m-%d")

comment_sentiments_with_date <- single_word_with_date %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>%
  count(index = date %/% month(date) , sentiment) %>%
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
```

This is the dataframe line is the comment number (e.g. line 2 comment had several words in it), date is datetime, word is a string.

```
> head(single_word_with_date)
     line       date     word
1       1 2011-11-16     love
2       2 2012-04-13   random
2.1     2 2012-04-13 question
2.8     2 2012-04-13 answered
2.14    2 2012-04-13   darwin
2.19    2 2012-04-13  purpose
```

Comment: Can you share representative sample of the your data using `dput` ? Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I added the first few rows of the dateframe to my question... Sorry about that

Comment: What is `n` in `spread` ? Do you have another column named `n` in your data that you have not shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

single_word_with_date %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>%
  group_by(quarter = paste(format(date, '%Y'), quarters(date), sep = '-')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sentiment, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative) -> result

result
```